# Email Doesn't Send(Type safe plugin for email ;version:Play 2.2.1 ,Scala 2.10.2)

Tags: scala, email

I am not sure whether this piece of code should send email to an email address or not or just Mock emailer which just prints values .Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
I took help from here:
https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer

I am not getting any error...But didn't get anything when I check email...

### application.scala

```
val mail = use[MailerPlugin].email
mail.setSubject("MailAPage email")
mail.setRecipient("Dummy Recipient <a.....@gmail.com>")
mail.setFrom("Six Hats <shat...@gmail.com>")
//or use a list
mail.setBcc(List("Dummy1 <d...@gmail.com>", "dummy2 <m....@gmail.com>"): _*)
//sends html
mail.sendHtml("<html>html</html>")
//sends text/text
mail.send("text")
//sends both text and html
mail.send("text", "<html>html</html>")
```

Should I have to do anything else ?

Comment: What's in your `conf/application.conf`? In particular hostname and port?

Answer (score 0):

You would expect an exception if you can't connect to the mail server. For instance in case  hostname or port is incorrectly configured.

If you are able to connect to the mail server/agent then all the errors that will happen there most probably will not reach your code.

For example if you run postfix or sendmail on localhost 25. You can connect to it and tell it to send the mail but you would not know if it did it.

It could be that your ISP is blocking outgoing SMTP traffic, and things like that. Do you use any particular mail server like gmail or the one provided by your ISP?

Comment: yes I am using smtp mail server ....

I use this configuration from application.conf file


Do I need to do else to connect to the smtp mail server ?
here is my smtp.conf

      # enable moocking - disable this for production
    mock=true

    # SMTP server
    # (mandatory)
    # defaults to gmail
    host=smtp.gmail.com

    # SMTP port
    # defaults to 25
    port=25

    # Use SSL
    # for GMail, this should be set to true
    ssl=true
 
    # authentication user
    user="s....@gmail.com"
    password="six...."

Comment: Try different port: 465, `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` to check connectivity.

Comment: can't tell from the swallowed newlines, but did you say you have `mock=true` in your config? 'cause that might do it...

Comment: Now I am getting this exception  "[EmailException: From address required] in MailerPlugin.scala "  @rob I commented mock=true

Comment: Now I am getting this exception  "[EmailException: From address required] "  @rob I commented mock=true line

Comment: Did you try setting From address?

Comment: Yes..like this    mail.addFrom(current.configuration.getString("smtp.user").get) ... error "value addFrom is not a member of com.typesafe.plugin.MailerAPI"